# How do I check for specific words in a list of tokenized sentences and then mark them as one or zero?

Tags: python, list, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to map specific words in a list to another list of tokenized sentences and if the word is found in the sentence then I append a 1 to a list of its category and 0 to the rest of categories.
For example:

```
category_a=["stain","sweat","wet","burn"]
category_b=["love","bad","favorite"]
category_c=["packaging","delivery"]
tokenized_sentences=['this deodorant does not stain my clothes','i love this product','i sweat all day']
for i in category_a:
    for j in tokenized_sentences:
          if(i in nltk.word_tokenize(j)):
                 list_a.append(j)
                 tag_a,tag_b,tag_c=([],)*3
                 tag_a.append(1)
                 tag_b.append(0)
                 tag_c.append(0)
                 final=tag_a+tag_b+tag_c
```

Similarly for category_b and category_c

```
Expected output:this deodorant does not stain my clothes-->[1,0,0]
                i love this product-->[0,1,0]
                i sweat all day-->[1,0,0]
                great fragrance-->[0,0,0]
```

I am getting duplicate outputs for each sentence like: i love this product-->[1,0,0]
i love this product-->[1,0,0] and
also like this:[i love this product,i sweat all day]-->[0,1,0]

```
Also, if a sentence has words from two different categories Ex: 'this product does not stain and i love it'
the expected output would be [1,1,0]
```

How do I get the output in the required format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
category_b = ["love", "bad", "favorite"]
category_c = ["packaging", "delivery"]
sentences = ['this deodorant does not stain my clothes', 'i love this product', 'i sweat all day']

results = []

for sentence in sentances:
    cat_a = 0
    cat_b = 0
    cat_c = 0
    for word in sentance.split():
        if cat_a == 0:
            cat_a = 1 if word in category_a else 0
        if cat_b == 0:
            cat_b = 1 if word in category_b else 0
        if cat_c == 0:
            cat_c = 1 if word in category_c else 0

    results.append((sentance, [cat_a, cat_b, cat_c]))


print(results)
```

This code will check if each sentence contains word of each of the given categories and save both of them (the sentence and result) in form of a tuple. All tuples will be appended to a list called *results*.

Output:

```
[('this deodorant does not stain my clothes', [1, 0, 0]), ('i love this product', [0, 1, 0]), ('i sweat all day', [1, 0, 0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your order of comparisons is off - and I do not get this

> ```
>          tag_a,tag_b,tag_c=([],)*3
>          tag_a.append(1)
>          tag_b.append(0)
>          tag_c.append(0)
>          final=tag_a+tag_b+tag_c
> ```

stuff you do - you never check the correct things.

This is how it would work:

```
import nltk

category_a=["stain","sweat","wet","burn"]
category_b=["love","bad","favorite"]
category_c=["packaging","delivery"]
tokenized_sentences=['this deodorant does not stain my clothes',
                     'i love this product','i sweat all day']
r = []

for j in tokenized_sentences:
    r = []
    for c in [category_a,category_b,category_c]:
        print(nltk.word_tokenize(j), c) # just a debug print whats compared here
        if any( w in c for w in nltk.word_tokenize(j)):
            r.append(1)
        else:
            r.append(0)
    print(r) # print the result
```

Output:

```
['this', 'deodorant', 'does', 'not', 'stain', 'my', 'clothes'] ['stain', 'sweat', 'wet', 'burn']
['this', 'deodorant', 'does', 'not', 'stain', 'my', 'clothes'] ['love', 'bad', 'favorite']
['this', 'deodorant', 'does', 'not', 'stain', 'my', 'clothes'] ['packaging', 'delivery']
[1, 0, 0]

['i', 'love', 'this', 'product'] ['stain', 'sweat', 'wet', 'burn']
['i', 'love', 'this', 'product'] ['love', 'bad', 'favorite']
['i', 'love', 'this', 'product'] ['packaging', 'delivery']
[0, 1, 0]

['i', 'sweat', 'all', 'day'] ['stain', 'sweat', 'wet', 'burn']
['i', 'sweat', 'all', 'day'] ['love', 'bad', 'favorite']
['i', 'sweat', 'all', 'day'] ['packaging', 'delivery']
[1, 0, 0]
```